# How to use the same component for nested routes routes in vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a view that have a list of items with a route:

```
{
  path: "/items",
  name: "items",
  component: () => import("./myViews/itemsView.vue")
},
```

if I click one of them I go to route:

```
{
  path: "/items/:id",
  name: "singleItem",
  ***component: () => import("./myViews/singleItemView.vue")***
},
```

inside that view I have another list of other items and I need the route to look like this:

```
{
  path: "/items/:id/:subId",
  name: "singleSubItem",
  ***component: () => import("./myViews/singleItemView.vue")***
},
```

and I need to use the same component singleItemView for both routes.

when I am at "/items/:id "I am listening from a value emitted from a child component and then pushing the route like this:

```
<myComponent @completed="$router.push({name: 'singleSubItme', params: {id: 'id', subId:'subId'})"></myComponent>
```

The url does change but it keeps the same component with the same state and I want it to reload.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two Path with same route and same component - Vue js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47160546/two-path-with-same-route-and-same-component-vue-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is add `:key` to your `router-view` to force it re-render

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

You can also watch `$route` inside `singleItemView.vue` to have custom action (for example, call API)

```
watch: {
  '$route'(to, from) {
    const {id, subId} = to.params
    if (subId) {
      // do something
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view> did the trick